# Typescript cannot set a property of undefined

Tags: typescript

I have the following in my Angular component:

```
class Test implements ....{
  duration:{from:number, to:number}

  constructor(){
    this.duration.from = "ddd";//set after some calculations
     this.duration.to = "ddd";
  }
}
```

The above returns an error of *"cannot set property `from` of undefined"*.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You did declare that `duration` was of type `{from:number, to:number}`. That does not initialize it. `this.duration` is `undefined` at the time the constructor runs. Use `this.duration = {from: 'ddd', to: 'ddd'}` to initialize it.

Comment: Hi, try declare `duration = {...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your class you define variable `duration` and specify it's type, however you do not initialize it, so the value of the variable remains `undefined`. Instead of assigning properties `this.duration.from` and `this.duration.to`, you should initialize variable:

```
class Test implements ....{
    duration:{from:number, to:number}

    constructor(){
        this.duration = {
            from: 1,
            to: 2
        };
    }
}
```